# How to remove a team project completely

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs

While using Team Foundation Server sometimes we have to delete our projects entirely and make them again from scratch. But while mapping, everytime we have to map our projects to a different folder. Deleting the old folder does not work at all, it creates another one while mapping. I guess there is a list that Visual Studio keeps about the TFS projects. But we cannot find it.

So how to delete a mapped TFS project entirely that we can map another project into THE SAME NAMED FOLDER?

Comment: ps i am trying to delete the files from clients, not the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `tfsdeleteproject` command from a visual studio command prompt. Here is the syntax:

```
tfsdeleteproject /server:your_tfs_server project_name
```

Note that when deleting TFS projects, you must be the project creator to delete the TFS project. If you weren’t the creator of the project, then you have to be a member of the “Site Collection Administrators” group on share point portal for the project, and you must be a member of the “Team Foundation Administrators” TFS group.

**EDIT**

For workspace deletes, use the following instructions:

Use the command line utility `tf`.

You can get a list of all workspaces by bringing up a Visual Studio Command Prompt and using the following command:

```
c:\>tf workspaces /owner:*
```

You should see your problem workspace in the list as well as it's owner.
You can delete the workspace with the following command (substitute BUILDSERVER, WORKSPACENAME and OWNERNAME accordingly):

```
C:\>tf workspace /delete /server:BUILDSERVER WORKSPACENAME;OWNERNAME
```

Refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y901w7se%28VS.80%29.aspx) for more info.

So you could delete the workspace and recreate it, then reimport your projects.

Comment: no no, not the server, i was talking about deleting from clients